# XQUERY GOUP BY CLAUSE

Tags: xquery-3.0

I am running XQuery using group by clause with large collection ,But I am getting out of main memory , it is taking huge memory to execute,our requirement should use the group by clause,Is their any alternate to group by.Please do the needful

Comment: Please include both code and example data. What XQuery processor are you using? How much main memory can your system provide, did you increase Java's heap size (if it's written in Java)?